# Data Integrity attack

Tags: security, data-integrity

I need to construct three examples of different kinds of attacks against the CIA model.
Now C and A I had no problems finding lots material for, but I'm having no luck at all
finding exaples of Integrity attacks.

I understand that attacks on Integrity either aim to make data un-usable or wrong.
Making it unusable could propably be made with catching IP packets and scrambling
their data. Is this at all correct?

Any tips for searching for this is also helpful as I'm not quite sure of the terms
as my studies are not in english. I've tried all variations of "Data Integrity",
"Data Integrity Attack" etc., but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that kind of integrity is important, it's not what CIA is referring to.

Integrity in this case means "what I sent is what you received." Whether or not what I sent you was valid to begin with is not of concern in terms of the transmission of the data.

For something to have integrity you would have to be able to say with certainty that it has or has not been modified.

So to attack that, you would have to find a way to modify the data/packet in transit (man in the middle?) in such a manner that the recipient wouldn't know it. Can you think of a way to do this, or at least what information/access you would need to devise a technique for this?

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I was thinking about this a bit wrong. I've stumbled upon man in the middle attacks before but it didn't pop into my mind here. I thought it would be under Confidentiality.

Comment: Man in the middle is part of confidentiality attacks as well. Confidentiality says "Can I read it?" while Integrity says "Can I change it?"

Comment: As far as what you were considering for integrity, you might find http://xkcd.com/327/ to be of interest. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like you stated, an attack on integrity would involve making data incorrect, either subtly or obviously.  Think about a student breaking into their school's computer to modify their grades; that is an attack on integrity, since no information is revealed that shouldn't be and the computer remains usable despite the attack.

Comment: @glowcoder: I don't think the CIA model is only about network attacks; see http://it.med.miami.edu/x904.xml or http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/the-cia-triad/488.

Comment: you're absolutely correct that it applies to many different aspects of information security. I used to work at a DoD research firm, and the steps to information security regarding those elements were suprisingly similar to methods employed in network security concepts.